# What could cause a HTTP 403 Forbidden when using LDAP?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Our administrators have Directory Assistance being used and in that they have an LDAP record.  Sporadically users will get a HTTP 403 Forbidden and to resolve this our security team runs a tool that re-orders the DN entries as shown in the NAB.  We have yet to figure out why the order of the DN entries in the LDAP catalog would be causing this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these users getting a 403 when accessing an app that is being served up by Domino's http task but the Domino server is using some external LDAP server for authentication? Or are they getting it from an app on some other server that is using Domino's LDAP for authentication?

Comment: Domino server is using some external LDAP server for authentication.   Our thought is that the attribute being returned isn't the NotesName so the authentication fails.  We have some apps on other servers being served up by the Domino's http task that don't cause this issue.

Comment: There are debug techniques when Domino is the LDAP server, but not for when Domino is acting as the LDAP client, AFAIK. It's up to the admins of the LDAP server to look at their logs to see what query Domino is sending, and figure out why it is resulting in a failure. I've seen a case where a "temporary" record that was left in the LDAP server by some sort of synch process had the same DN as the user record, and the scope of the directory search was not limited just to the user subtree, so that caused a conflict. It would be a wild coincidence if that was the case for you, though.

Comment: It appears the issue is only occurring when 'http' links for databases are being clicked from another custom built non-Domino application are retrieving the first attribute from the LDAP server and using that to authenticate the user.  Unfortunately, the entry in some instances isn't the NotesName which is why it seems is causing the Forbidden.  I say this also because when we have the LDAP attributes fixed so that the first entry is the NotesName all works as it should.